# Excel date precision and unexpected discard of <1s accuracy

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, date-time

## The Problem

A datetime cell contains data with accuracy down to tenths of a second or greater precision, but discards this accuracy to "second"-level precision when the cell data is edited, even if nothing is changed.

## To Re-create

Obviously elements of this could be locale, machine and/or user specific, but the below represents my experience on 2 desktops and a laptop, always Excel 2010, UK.

1. Enter "19/04/2015 13:26:15.456" into a cell without the quotes (UK format, so 04/19/2015 in US presumably); press enter so the contents are accepted.

   - Excel decides to format this as "mm:ss.0", rendering it as "26:15.5"
2. Move back to the cell in question **without editing it yet**

   - it can be seen to have "lost" the precision in the formula bar, showing as "19/04/2015  13:26:15" without fractions of a second.  However, the cell still shows "26:15.5", indicating by the .5 tail that the accuracy is still actually present.
3. CTRL-1 and change the Format from "mm:ss.0" to "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.000".  It now renders correctly as "19/04/2015 13:26:15.456" in the cell (but still without the .456 in the formula bar).
4. This is the crux of the problem; now press F2, then press enter; i.e. "edit" the cell but without changing anything.  The precision < 1 second is discarded and the cell now shows "19/04/2015 13:26:15.**000**"

This means if I edit the date portion of a cell (ie change April to May, or advance a year, etc.), or simply accidentally double-click it, I throw away the decimal precision every time.  Is there any way I can prevent this happening?

To further prove that the value is changing and not just the formatting, I've added a formula to an adjacent cell to render the date as a decimal (10dp), and the value only changes immediately after step 4 above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a cell setup as date/time like the following:

[image]

Select the cell and run this short macro:

```
Sub beforeEDIT()
    Dim s As String

    With ActiveCell
        s = .Text
        .ClearContents
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        .Value = s
    End With
End Sub
```

It will convert the cell into pure text *(and preserve milliseconds)*.  You can then edit the cell, change month or day, etc.

When you have completed your edits, run this second macro to convert the text back into date/time.

```
Sub afterEDIT()
    With ActiveCell
        .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.000"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice one.  My efforts to convert to string/text didn't quite manage to preserve the layout (converted to numeric representation).  Sorry I can't upvote - rep too low :(